# How can I verify the health of initramfs

Tags: 14.04, lts, initramfs

Running 14.04 LTS I saw a bunch of errors mentioning initramfs during a software update. ("update-initramfs generating /boot/initrd.img" repeated many times)

How can I test/review/repair my setup, to make sure I will be able to boot next time (haven't tried rebooting yet)

Comment: Please post those errors in your OP so all can see, and _update-initramfs generating /boot/initrd.img_ doesn't necessarily mean its an error. It could simply mean that changes where made severally to it and hence it had to be re-generated.

Comment: I can't reproduce them. How can I be sure that re-generation process was successful?

Comment: If your system _boots_ normally and every thing works fine then its ok else its not.

Comment: I haven't tried rebooting after getting those msgs. Wanted to see if there is a way to check the initramfs  is ok before try rebooting.

Comment: The fact that your where you are means its ok, if it had a problem you won't be there. Again I think Ubuntu does a _file system check using fsck tool_ at boot but you can  do so too at boot but I it can't be done when the _file system_ have been mounted AFAIK.

Comment: You should be able to find the data in /var/log/apt/term.log or /var/log/apt/term.log.*.gz for older logs.